# Python - Spawn/Run a New Process Using Shell's stdin and stdout

Tags: python

I want to execute a non-python program from within python. The non-python program prompts the user for a password so I want stdin to be routed to that subprocess. Similarly, the subprocess has some stdout which I want to be printed to the console. When the subprocess terminates, I would like the parent python program to continue executing.

This seems so simple yet I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it. The problem is that there are too many ways to do something very similar (os.spawn, os.exec, commands.*, subprocess.*, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - subprocesses and the python shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336996/python-subprocesses-and-the-python-shell)

Comment: Similar, but not an exact duplicate. That questioner wanted a solution that would work in IDLE (which significantly complicates things) and specifically wanted to use subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(whatever, stdin=sys.stdout, stdout=sys.stdin)
```

However, are you sure that the password comes in through stdin? Command-line passwords generally use a different facility.

Comment: Just tested it, I suppose this rsync uses stdin. Thanks!